# To what extent can phase transitions be made rigorous?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, critical-phenomena

It seems a lot of physical intuition in statistical mechanics, for example phase transitions, critical temperature, scaling hypothesis, renormalization group methods etc. should have a purely mathematical formulation; my question is: to what extent can this be done? Can we prove statements from a standard textbook (say Statistical mechanics by Huang) in a mathematically rigorous way?

A more specific example: it is well know that the 2D ising model with no external magnetic field has a 2nd order phase transition, can this be proven rigorously?

Comment: Are you looking for exactly solvable systems with phase transitions? The free bose gas is solvable in terms of polylogarithms and has a phase transition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a lot can be proven rigorously, at least for lattice systems.

There are entire books on this topic. Here are a few (the first one can be legally downloaded for free):

- Friedli and Velenik, [*Statistical Mechanics of Lattice Systems: a Concrete Mathematical Introduction*](https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook/)
- Georgii, [*Gibbs Measures and Phase Transitions*](https://www.degruyter.com/document/doi/10.1515/9783110250329/html)
- Ruelle, [*Statistical Mechanics: Rigorous Results*](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/4090)
- Simon, [*The Statistical Mechanics of Lattice Gases*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691636436/the-statistical-mechanics-of-lattice-gases-volume-i)
- Prum, [*Stochastic Processes on a Lattice and Gibbs Measures*](https://link.springer.com/book/9780792310693)
- Presutti, [*Scaling Limits in Statistical Mechanics and Microstructures in Continuum Mechanics*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-73305-8)
- Fernández, Fröhlich and Sokal, [*Random Walks, Critical Phenomena, and Triviality in Quantum Field Theory*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-662-02866-7)
- Israel, [*Convexity in the Theory of Lattice Gases*](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691635002/convexity-in-the-theory-of-lattice-gases)
- Ellis, [*Entropy, Large Deviations, and Statistical Mechanics*](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/3-540-29060-5)
- etc.

Concerning the specific list of topics you mention, let me mention that rigorous results about the critical behavior remain scarce. Exceptions are:

- in some planar models (in particular, the Ising model), a lot of progress has been made in the last 15 years, since the introduction of the Schramm-Löwner evolution made it possible to prove conformal invariance; ([one example](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/2015/181-3/p05))
- in some cases, it is possible to implement rigorous renormalization group methods to obtain information about the critical behavior of nonintegrable perturbations of integrable models; ([one example](https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.04458))
- it is also possible to implement rigorously the renormalization group method in sufficiently high dimensions; ([one example](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-981-32-9593-3))
- in sufficiently high dimensions (at the very least, above the upper critical dimension), an alternative way of obtaining detailed information about the critical behavior of a variety of models (including Ising) is the lace expansion. ([one example](https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.09856))

As to your question about the order of the phase transition in the Ising model, I don't think any of the books I mention above proves the fact that the latter is of second order. In dimension $2$, this follows, for instance, from Onsager's exact expression for the free energy. In higher dimensions, continuity of the magnetization at $\beta_{\rm c}$ is proved in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.1937).